# Brew - Install specific version of brew package

Tags: homebrew

How I can install an specific version of a brew package?
Like

```
brew uninstall rbenv (v. 2.1.2)
```

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3987683/2037637)

Comment: @hoosierEE yes, but what happend when you need add a custom version (or at least not the lasted version listed in `brew`) ?